# Exclude word header and footer content from search SP 2013

Tags: search, search-results, crawling

Having text based header and footer content in word files, how can I exclude this content from either being indexed in the first place or being displayed in the search result?

Example; having a collection of word files, all with the the company slogan "foo, not bar".

How can I either configure my search application or filter the search result to be able to search for any document containing the word "foo" in their actual body, but excluding all the document just holding this phrase in their header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its not possible. When its in the document it will be crawled - but - usually the information is very low in header/footer so you wont get relevant hits.

Comment: Seems like it :( 

The strange this is that the search result present hits in document footers way up in my result list.

The "best" solutions I've come up with so far is to render the document header and footer with an image to exclude this data from the search result.

Comment: Yes, images in the corporate template instead of text is a solution - but the business most likely does not acceppt this.